# x + y == ans; Statement has no effect (C++)

Tags: c++, console, calculator, effect

I know I could write a calculator in a more efficient way, but I'm at my last step so I wanna finish this.

The warnings appear after the usleep()

In my console I get 0 as my answer and I get 4 warnings saying that x +,-,*,/ ==ans doesn't do anything.

This is probably a dumb mistake but plz haalp. I'm a beginner in C++ and programming in general.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //X is first number, Y is second
    int ans = 0;
    string i;
    int x;
    int y;
    string op;

    cout << "This is a four function integer calculator." << endl << endl << "Type 'help' at any time to view the help screen" << endl<< endl<<"Insert your first number" << endl;
    cin >> i;
    if(i=="help"){
    cout << "Help Menu" << endl << endl << "add = +" << endl <<"subtract = -" << endl <<"multiply = *" << endl <<"divide = /"<< endl;
    cin >> i;
    }else{
    stringstream(i) >> x;
    cout << "Insert your operator" << endl;
    cin >> op;
    cout << "Insert your second number" << endl;
    cin >> y;
    cout << "The calculator will now preform " << x << " " << op << " " << y << endl;
    usleep(1000000);
    if(op== "+"){
        x + y == ans;
        return ans;
    }else if(op=="-"){
        x - y == ans;
        return ans;
    }else if(op=="*"){
        x * y == ans;
        return ans;
    }else if(op=="/"){
        x / y == ans;
        return ans;
    }else{
    cout << "You inserted an illegal operator, please restart the application" << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << ans << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `==` does equality comparison. Did you mean to use assignment (`=`)? It seems you got the order of the operands mixed up, though. Aside from this, you should **always** verify that your read attempts were successful (e.g., `if (std::cin >> i) { ... }`) and returning `ans` from `main()` also won't do you much good.

Comment: +1 for what Dietmar said, and also - you try with `return ans` statements to return the result of calculations from `main` function. It will not work as intended - normally you should return 0 from `main` if there were no errors. Try rather to output the result to `cout`.

Answer (score 2):

`==` is the comparison operator. So with

```
x + y == ans;
```

you check if `x + y` equals `ans` and then discard the result of the comparison. This does nothing, thus the warning.

If you want to assign `x + y` to `ans`, use

```
ans = x + y;
```

Note that `ans` has to be on the left hand side.

Comment: Im trying to change the value of ans though

Comment: @DGSec `ans = x + y;` does change the value of `ans` to `x + y`. If that is not what you want, not need to clarify your question.

Comment: Thanks man that was it, but why didn't it work when I did x + y = ans; ?

Comment: @DGSec Because `= ` assigns its right hand side to its left hand side, not the other way around. If it would work both ways, how would the compiler know what `x = y;` is supposed to do?